# Developing a chat application in android

Tags: java, android, servlets, google-cloud-messaging, chat

I am looking to develop a chat application in android. I know core java and android well but I dont know java sockets and servlets. Are java sockets and servlets necessary to develop an android chat application?

Which api should I use to develop a chat application in android? What are the java and android concepts needed to develop an android chat application?

If I am to develop a chat applicatioon using Google cloud messaging in android, is knowledge of java sockets and servlets mandatory?

Comment: my advise to you is use Third party Libs like smack based on XMPP

Comment: Are servlets necessary for using 3rd party libs

Comment: not really .. most of 3rd party libs got thier own db for saving data.. and Push Notifications implemetions

Comment: How much time will it take to learn the concept of servlets if I start?

Comment: about a month or so..

Comment: Is it a tht difficult concept tht it takes such a long tym to learn it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to create an instant chat service, I would personally recommend the [Sinch SMS API](https://www.sinch.com/products/sms-api/) or [Smack](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack). However, if you want to use the Google messaging API, you might want to follow a tutorial such as the one [here](http://www.appsrox.com/android/tutorials/instachat/) just to get you familiarized with writing the required server integration code (servlet use is explained so prior knowledge is not necessarily mandatory). Its really a matter of preference and comfort so choose whatever you think you will be able to work with. I hope this helps!

> And no knowledge of sockets and servlets is not necessarily mandatory depending on what path you choose. Most api's handle this for you.

EDIT: If you don't like the options I've provided, you could try [this](https://quickblox.com/) however I do believe in your case Sinch would be the best approach.

Comment: Is sinch sms api good enough to make a chat app for a client who is paying you large amount of money. and tht link uses servlets.

Comment: I am aware that this link uses servlets however it explains it as it goes so prior knowledge is not necessarily required. As for sinch, it is as powerful as you code it to be so in other words yes.

Comment: I think it's better to use Sinch Instant messaging if you want real time chat!